# CSS- display property

Tags: css

Which of the following values for the display property makes an element a block-level element and also allows other elements to be positioned next to it?

A) block
B )inline
C)inline-block
D)none

Which one is correct? A,B,C or D

Comment: `flex` and `grid`. :p

Comment: You would probably learn more by looking up descriptions of block etc on MDN and working out the answer for yourself.

Comment: Hi, 'none' make elements disappear, block or inline is the default value for tags based on which tag you use, for example, p element or div is by default a block element, or span is an inline element. but for your question, the correct answer is C.
you can learn more about them in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php)

Comment: No display property value, on its own, makes an element both block level and allows other elements next to it. The float property does, but it does so in conjunction with any of A, B, or C as well a many other display values.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is C) inline-block.

Comment: This is wrong. Inline-block elements are block containers, but they are not block-level.

Answer (score -3):

inline-block. It allows dimensions (height and width) while also allowing items to be positioned next to it.

Comment: This is wrong. Inline-block elements are block containers, but they are not block-level.